# Columnfilter works vertical instead of horizontally

Tags: javascript, datatables

I use ColumnFilterWidgets like in this example http://datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/index.html

But in my program it works not properly (vertical instead of horizontally).

There are no error-messages displayed in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the css-files? Did you include the complete file-structure from the widget and DataTables?